# ESB Toolkit. Itinerary Endpoint Outbound Location not set

Tags: biztalk, uddi, esb-toolkit-2.0

I have an Itinerary as follows

Receive a Message
Resolve two endpoints using UDDI ( Messaging Extender containing two resolvers)
then Off Ramp Extender
Apply Map using Message extender(using BRE)
OffRamp

The result i am looking for is two messages(both are exactly same) will need to be sent to two different endpoints with different maps applied

however in the BRE to resolve the map Endpoint Outbound Location is empty

can an one explain why this is happening

Regards
Arun

Answer (score 0):

If the BRE Policy to resolve the Map uses  the message/MessageType in the if clause, you have to set the "RecognizeMessageFormat" and "UseMsg" properties on the Resolver to True.